# Return ALL intersections array javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, intersection, array-intersect

My current code:

```
    function intersect(first, second) {
    var temp = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < first.length; i++){
        for(var k = 0; k < second.length; k++){
            if(first[i] == second[k]){
                temp.push( first[i]);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

  return temp;
}
```

How can I change this so it returns ALL the intersections indices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the indices to your result;

```
function intersect(first, second) {
  var temp = [];
  for(var i = 0; i < first.length; i++){
    for(var k = 0; k < second.length; k++){
      if(first[i] == second[k]){
        temp.push([i, k]); // push i and k as an array
      }
    }
  }

  return temp;
}
```

Also remove the `break;` if you want recurring exact intersections to be selected also.

**Find a running example here: http://jsfiddle.net/0tL9sk5w/1**

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but won't that break statement cause it to only return the first match in the second array?

Comment: Indeed, if in the second array a second exact same intersection occurs it is filtered by the break, so it has to be removed. I will edit it accordingly, thanks.

Comment: thank you... can't believe i didn't catch this part in all my attemtps  temp.push([i, k])

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is to push the two indexes as an array

instead of :

```
temp.push( first[i]);
```

you need to do this :

```
temp.push([i,k]);
```